# Can't install puppeteer package on node

Tags: node.js, node-modules, puppeteer

I am facing problem while installing puppeteer package.

[image: Error Screenshot]

My NPM version : `6.9.0`

Node version : `v10.16.0`

Tried with :

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

But it was no help.

I found the similar question over stackoverflow and went with this 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959038/npm-stuck-giving-the-same-error-eisdir-illegal-operation-on-a-directory-read-a/42677294#42677294). But still couldn't figure out how to resolve mine.

Answer (score 1):

What is [cacache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cacache)?

> cacache is a Node.js library for managing local key and content address caches. It's really fast, really good at concurrency, and it will never give you corrupted data, even if cache files get corrupted or manipulated.
>
> It was originally written to be used as npm's local cache, but can just as easily be used on its own.

## Fix 1

Copying this answer from [npm.community](https://npm.community/t/global-installs-sudo-npm-i-g-fail-on-mac-after-6-5-upgrade-works-fine-after-6-4-1-downgrade/4082/13) and adding a bit more,

Changing the ownership of files and then avoiding use of sudo is a possible work-around for EISDIR with global installs using sudo. Assuming this is your personal computer, and installing to default location on Mac:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin
```

Then try your command again **without sudo**. e.g.

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Now, **clean the cache**,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

And install your package normally **without sudo**,

```
npm i puppeteer
```

## Fix 2

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55739671/6161265), the answerer had same problem when he upgraded to **npm 6.9.0**, the solution was to reinstall and upgrade node,

```
brew reinstall node
```

## Fix 3

An [old issue on npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13528) related to .staging provided this fix.

Try to delete the package lock files and reinstall the packages,

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
npm install
```